# Angular 8 build breaks due to: SyntaxError: 'return' outside of function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-cli

I have an angular 8 app with ionic 4. After updating the package to the newest angular libs, the production build crashes returning `SyntaxError: 'return' outside of function`.

This is the full error generated by the angular client under C:\Users\C\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-ew2jmU\angular-errors.log:

```
[error] SyntaxError: 'return' outside of function
at j (C:\app\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:18871)
at c (C:\app\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:27588)
at C:\app\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:31818
at C:\app\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:28319
at C:\app\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:49983
at oe (C:\app\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:50120)
at Object.nr [as minify] (C:\app\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:1:320348)
at terserMangle (C:\app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\process-bundle.js:181:35)
at Object.process (C:\app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\process-bundle.js:79:34)
at execFunction (C:\app\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:155:17)
at execHelper (C:\app\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:139:5)
at execFunction (C:\app\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:164:5)
at execMethod (C:\app\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:148:3)
at process.on.request (C:\app\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:64:7)
at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
at emit (internal/child_process.js:820:12)
```

These are the dependencies in my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/pwa": "0.803.19",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular": "4.11.5",
    "@mapbox/togeojson": "0.16.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0",
    "@turf/turf": "5.1.6",
    "anchorme": "1.1.2",
    "angular-6-social-login": "1.1.1",
    "bcryptjs": "2.4.3",
    "chart.js": "2.9.3",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "0.7.0",
    "country-data": "0.0.31",
    "croppie": "2.6.4",
    "d3-array": "2.4.0",
    "geoblaze": "0.2.2",
    "is-uuid": "1.0.2",
    "jointjs": "2.2.1",
    "jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
    "kalmanjs": "1.1.0",
    "libphonenumber-js": "1.7.27",
    "localforage": "1.7.3",
    "localforage-cordovasqlitedriver": "1.8.0",
    "localforage-driver-memory": "1.0.5",
    "mathjs": "6.2.5",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "2.1.1",
    "ngforage": "5.0.1",
    "ngx-bar-rating": "1.1.0",
    "ngx-color": "4.1.0",
    "ol": "6.1.1",
    "ol-ext": "3.1.7",
    "pptxgenjs": "2.6.0",
    "shpjs": "3.4.3",
    "svg-pan-zoom": "3.6.1",
    "uuid": "3.3.3",
    "core-js": "3.4.2",
    "rxjs": "6.5.3",
    "rxjs-tslint": "0.1.7",
    "zone.js": "0.10.2"
},

"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.803.19",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.803.19",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "8.3.19",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "8.3.19",
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.19",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.14",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "2.0.13",
    "@types/backbone": "1.3.46",
    "@types/chart.js": "2.9.2",
    "@types/country-data": "0.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.3.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.6",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "2.2.1",
    "@types/mathjs": "6.0.2",
    "@types/node": "12.0.8",
    "@types/shpjs": "3.4.0",
    "codelyzer": "5.1.0",
    "gzip-all": "1.0.0",
    "replace-in-file": "4.2.0",
    "source-map-support": "0.5.16",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.10",
    "webpack-node-externals": "1.7.2",
    "ts-node": "8.5.2",
    "tslint": "5.20.1",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  },
```

And this is the global version of angular & ionic installed:

```
PS C:\app> ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.3.19
Node: 10.15.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.19
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.19
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.19
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.19
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.19
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.19
@angular/cli                      8.3.19
@angular/pwa                      0.803.19
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.19
@schematics/angular               8.3.19
@schematics/update                0.803.19
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2

PS C:\app> ionic --version
5.2.7
PS C:\app>
```

Since the error only appears during build with the --prod flag, I assume this issue must be within of one of the libraries, supposedly one of the angular libs, as it was them I changed. Unfortunately it does not tell me where... I ran several times `npm i`, cleared the npm cache, deleted the node_modules folder... nothing helped.

Did anyone encounter the same error?
Is it a bug with angular itself or any clue on where to start looking for?

**UPDATE**
I managed to delimit the error to these to packages:

```
    @angular-devkit/architect
    @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

When I downgrade them to `0.803.6`, I don't get the error and everything is fine. However `0.803.19` definately breaks it. So, is this an angular bug then?

Comment: _After updating the package to the newest angular libs_. How did you update? That might make a difference.

Comment: Please first check your components,  you could have accidentally deleted the bracket at end of function

Comment: Changing the version number in the packages.json file and running npm i.

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan
could be, but then the typescript compiler would throw the same error when running a build without the prod flag, right?

Comment: maybe yes, but yesterday I have the same problem, I have accidentally deleted the atribute name from template. it doesn't gave me any errors but website was broken.

Comment: Please can you check the link from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Bad_return_or_yield

Answer (score -1):

Since it's happening only with --prod, most likely this would be issue in ahead of time compilation and a definite code issue. From your logs I see error in terser module. I would recommend you to check the webpack plugins.